# Spring MVC: Arbitrary indexes have null properties when submitting large lists of objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-form

In my project, I have a **form** to set permissions to users which **has some tables** in it. When I **submit this form**, which has lots of objects inside lists, **some properties of some arbitrary indexes of the lists are null when the data reaches the controller**.

Every table has a bunch of objects that the admin sets to Visible, Not Visible or Downloadable.

Those tables are filled with lists from backend, and they are stored inside a `PermisoList` object:

```
public class PermisoList { 

  List<PermisoProductoForm> permisosProducto;
  List<PermisoCarpetaForm> permisosCarpeta;
  List<PermisoTipoDocForm> permisosTipoDoc;
  List<PermisoAgenteClienteForm> permisosAgenteCliente;
  List<PermisoIdiomaForm> permisosIdioma;
  List<PermisoPaisForm> permisosPais;
  List<PermisoEmpresaForm> permisosEmpresa;
  List<PermisoUsuarioProductoForm> permisosUsuarioProducto;
  List<PermisoUsuarioEmpresaForm> permisosUsuarioEmpresa;
  ...
}
```

Those lists are referenced on frontend inside this form:

```
<sf:form id="form" action="${action}"   class="form-horizontal" method="post" modelAttribute="permisosList" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

For instance:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla_permisos3">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><%=Languages.getString("Idioma")%></th>
        <th><%=Languages.getString("Permiso")%></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${permisosList.permisosIdioma}" var="permiso" varStatus="counter">
        <tr>
            <sf:input path="permisosIdioma[${counter.index}].idioma.idIdioma" type="hidden"/>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><c:out value="${permiso.idioma.nombre}"/></td>
            <td align="center">
                <sf:select class="form-control" path="permisosIdioma[${counter.index}].permiso" type="number">
                    <sf:option value="0">
                        <c:out value="No visible" />
                    </sf:option>
                    <sf:option value="1">
                        <c:out value="Visible" />
                    </sf:option>
                    <sf:option value="2">
                        <c:out value="Descarga" />
                    </sf:option>
                </sf:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

This `modelAttribute` is sent to the frontend this way:

```
PermisoList permisosList = new PermisoList(permisosProd, permisosCarp, permisosTipoD, permisosAC, permisosIdioma, permisosPais, permisosEmpresa);
model.addAttribute("permisosList", permisosList);
```

Everything on frontend works well, but when I submit this lists to the backend, some elements of the lists have null properties. So, some information is lost in the process. **Why?**

For instance, this is my `PermisoIdiomaForm` object:

```
public class PermisoIdiomaForm {

  private Idioma idioma;
  private Integer permiso;
  ...
}
```

Once the data is submitted, for some indexes, maybe `idioma`, or its `idIdioma` or `permiso` are null. And on another submit, another index (or indexes) have the same issue. **Why?** And this only happens when there are more than about 200 objects.

I've checked out that **everything is OK at the frontend**. And, in fact, I've seen that **in my developer server** (Pivotal TC Server, the default one from STS IDE) **it works perfectly**. No properties are lost, no info is lost. Everything works OK.

With the same environtment, Tomcat 8 has the issue. So it's a **Server problem**.

And in **production**, we have a **Tomcat 8 and this problem exists**. This Tomcat 8 is in an Ubuntu 14 LTS.

**Even Pivotal TC Server has the issue installed on Ubuntu 14 LTS.**

**What is going on here? Why do I lose information when submitting to backend?**

I've tried:

- Add `initBinder` method to the controller and `binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(2048);`
- Add `maxPostSize="-1" maxParameterCount="-1" maxHeaderCount="-1"` to the Connector at server.xml.
- Try to use `Autopopulatinglist` instead of Lists or ArrayLists

**Does anyone know anything about this issue?** Any idea?
Any help or tip would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that on your development box everything works fine even if there are more than 200 objects?

Comment: That's right. Excuse me for my limited English. Using Pivotal TC on my dev environment this issue never happens.

Comment: I've "solved" this issue using AJAX. I'll post what I've done next days. It seems this issue is related to Spring Forms, some kind of misundersanting between it and the server.